# Using textAutoCorrect and textAutoComplete together in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, autocomplete, android-edittext

I was trying to create an EditText with
`android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textAutoComplete"`

Unfortunately Android won't let me use *`textAutoCorrect`* and *`textAutoComplete`* at the same time. *`textAutoCorrect`* gives me the ability to choose multiple options when I type (for spellcheck), and *`textAutoComplete`* lets me add a dropdown to supply custom completion choices for individual words.

However,when both are added, *`textAutoComplete`* seems to take precedence. Since this is a multi-line edittext, I want to be able to provide spellcheck as well as custom choices. I would think that this is possible since Google+'s composer allows spellcheck, but it also lets me mention users (which would be custom choices). MultiAutoCompleteTextViews add the *`textAutoComplete`* inputType to the view, so I can't use those either.

Can anybody help me come up with a solution to my problem?

Comment: If someone could tell me whether or not this is possible at all, that would be helpful too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation I would say that this is not possible.

```
textAutoCorrect     0x00008001   Can be combined with text and its variations to request auto-correction of text being input. Corresponds to TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT.
textAutoComplete    0x00010001   Can be combined with text and its variations to specify that this field will be doing its own auto-completion and talking with the input method appropriately. Corresponds to TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE.
```

You can read more about it here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType